# What does the bash command "rm *~" do?

Tags: bash, syntax, gnu-make

Does the bash command `rm *~` just remove files ending in tilde or is there a more advanced bash or gnu make pattern here?  Google does not seem able to search for this two symbol combination.  I found this in a Makefile clean: target.

Would gnu make ever create files with trailing ~'s using only the implicit rules?

Comment: People usually suggest that you "try it and see". But I guess that's not always a good plan with the `rm` command.

Comment: A good rule of thumb for testing rm is to change rm to ls. The files it lists are the files rm will delete

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `~` (tilde) character has a special meaning in a path in two cases:

```
~user        # the home directory of user
~/folder     # folder inside your home directory
```

For the most part, that's it. The command you refer to does exactly what it looks like it does: removes files whose names end in a tilde. Text editors such as emacs save backup copies of files under filenames ending in tildes.

So, this command is probably used to remove these backup copies from the current directory (but not subdirectories). One reason why one would want to do so is if the directory will be copied to a web server, as server-side code (e.g. PHP files) can contain sensitive information such as passwords.

Comment: Also, '~-' in some shells is equivalent to $OLDPWD (or the particular shell's equivalent to the last directory), and for completeness, '~' with no user name appended expands to $HOME

Comment: Just make sure not to introduce an extra space, as in `rm * ~`

Comment: This command has usually worked for me, but when I run it now , I get `rm: cannot remove '*~': No such file or directory`. Why does it fail now? I'm trying this command in Bash on Red Hat for the first time, while I have previously used Bash on Ubuntu, and Git Bash in Windows. Is there a difference between Bash on Red Hat and the other two Bash variants (if you can call Git Bash that)?

Answer (score 5):

As you guessed, `rm *~` just removes file with names ending with a tilde (~). Filenames ending with a tilde are usually backup files created by editors (in particular, emacs was one of the earlier editors to use this convention). After editing source code, it is common to have a number of these files left behind. This is why the `clean` target in the Makefile removes these.

Whether `*~` is some special bash pattern is not relevant for most makefiles, as /bin/sh is used by default to execute make recipes. Only if SHELL is set in the makefile will a different shell be used.

An easy way to see make's implicit rules is to run `make -p` in a directory without a makefile. You will get an error saying no targets specified, but make will also print out the implicit rules it is using. If you grep this output for a tilde, you'll see there are no implicit rules that name files with it.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, just what you said. Removes files ending with `~`.

Edit -> the only special meaning the `~` character may have, is as short-hand for the the current user's home directory (as `$HOME`), but only in the beginning of a path.

Answer (score 1):

I have used that command to erase files ending in "~". I think that there is no special escape character associated with the tilde symbol.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes to both

---

Actually, both of your possibilities are somewhat true.

There is no wildcard or special filename syntax associated with `~`, unless it occurs at the beginning of a word.

But the filename pattern ending in tilde *is* produced automatically by the `mv(1)` and `cp(1)` programs on most linux distros<sup>1</sup> if the `-b` *(backup)* option is specified and the target file exists.  A make rule on such a system might contain a `mv -b ...` or `cp -b ...` command.

---

<sup>1. But not on the Mac or BSD.</sup>

Comment: It seems that the -b option is not provided by the BSD mv and cp programs provided by Mac OSX.  I will have to look at this then next time I am working in linux.  Thanks for the tip, didn't know this existed.